# couchdb - replication - is there a way to replicate only part of the database?

Tags: couchdb, replication

I found in the manual where to give all the document-ids that needs replication.
but that looks too tedious.

Suppose that I have some indicator of when I last replicated, and I want to replicate next time from that point and on.

Or - I want to replicate to a second database only part of the data.

What ways do I have, except for specifying every single doc-id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filtered Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication)

Comment: Yes, and also, note that replication automatically begins from where it left of on the previous replication. (It does some checking first, to make sure it's the same source and target database, but if those checks pass, you automatically get "incremental" replication. All changes made since the last replication will propagate.)